# Populate items into SELECT with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble populating a SELECT with jquery, when the user writes the zipcode or part of it, it searches the database and returns this:

```
{"success":1,"id":"50","street":"Central One"},{"success":1,"id":"60","street":"Central Two"}
```

One success for each street it finds. For a single street and using a text input I'm using this

**UPDATE 1 - FULL CODE**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#zip').blur(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url : '../../controller/zip.php', 
            type : 'POST', 
            data: 'zip=' + $('#zip').val(), 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data){
                if(data.sucesso == 1){
                    $('#id').val(data.id);
                    $('#street').val(data.street);
                }
            }
       });   
return false;    
})
});
```

How can I change this so I can populate a select box.

Thanks

Comment: `if(data.sucess == 1){` check you mistyped in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would not encourage to do so; you're better off using a html-templating engine like [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) or [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)**.

Doing this kind of stuff in plain JS (string concatenation) is *gross*. It pollutes your sourcecode.

Anyways, this would do the trick to generate the necessary HTML:

```
function generateHTML(data){
    return data.reduce(function(o,n){
        return o+"<option value='"+n.id+"'>"+n.street+"</option>";
    },"");
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60bmbt4q/) to play with. If you need to filter for *success*, you could add a `filter()`

```
function generateHTML(data){
    return data.filter(function(x){
        return !!x.success;
    }).reduce(function(o,n){
        return o+"<option value='"+n.id+"'>"+n.street+"</option>";
    },"");
}
```

You could easily use `$("#selectBoxId").html(generateHTML(data))` to insert it to the DOM.

To fit it into your codebase, you should add it in the success handler:

```
success: function(data){
    function generateHTML(data){
        return data.reduce(function(o,n){
            return o+"<option value='"+n.id+"'>"+n.street+"</option>";
        },"");
    }
    $("select").html(generateHTML(data))
}
```

For the inner workings of `Array.prototype.reduce()` take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and for [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Depends on what you expected it to to. It shows "<option value='50'>Central One</option><option value='60'>Central Two</option>" in the developer console. The function simply generates the HTML as a string, which could be used further.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, Thanks, Think I got it now

Comment: It works in fiddle, I'm a total noob to js to I'm sorry for giving you girls trouble, I edited my post with the full script if anyone can help to change, cause I cant do it

Answer (score 1):

Use this for adding items to select box dynamically:

```
var $selectBox = $('#selectboxId');
$selectBox.empty();
$.each(data, function (idx, val) {
    if (val.success) {
        $selectBox.append($('<option>', {
            value: val.id,
            text:  val.street
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: I would suggest not doing the select query in the loop... store it in a variable outside the loop.... `var $selectBox = $('#selectboxId')`.

Comment: Also want to point out that appending each item within the loop will cause a redraw on each iteration, would be better to push them into an array and `append` the final collection to the select element which will reduce it to one redraw

Answer (score 1):

What is being passed back for a single address is a single object from which you can grab the information. When there are multiple responses you need to go through each of them and handle them.

When we look at [MDN's  article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples) it shows that we need a parent `<select>` tag and then we need to populate the children. The process would look like this:

- Find / create parent select
- [Optional] Remove previous child `<option>` tags
- Loop through responses

  - Create a new `<option>` element
  - Populate the `<option>` with the appropriate value and content
  - Append it to the parent `<select>`

Some things to be aware of, if you're clearing the previous addresses each time you get a response from the database you'll want to remove these previous `<option>`s. This can be done either by [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) if there are no other children in the parent or starting with the parent `<select>` and removing all child `<options>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON being returned is a list `[{...}, ..., {...}]`, then you can use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Here is the success callback:

```
function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.success) {
            // use item.id and item.street
        }
    });
}
```

If you have a `<select>` element, then you will want to be populating it with `<options>`, by appending an `<option>` element under each successful "if" branch in the `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the select element on the page and the data that is coming back from the server is an array of objects, this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '../../controller/zip.php', 
    type : 'POST', 
    data: 'zip=' + $('#zip').val(), 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var $items  = [];
        $.each(data, function(street) {
            if(data.success === 1) {
                $items.push($('<option />').attr({
                    value: street.id
                }).text(street.street));
            }
        });
        $('#your-select-element').append($items);
    }
});
```

Notice this isn't setting the value for one option, it is creating `<option>` tags for each of the response's streets and appending them to a `<select>` element.

Comment: You like the $-sign? ;) btw. there is no need to cache the selection of the DOM-element, although it might be a good habit to do so, in this case it is not necessary.

Comment: I am an American, so yes, I like the `$`. In actuality, I use the `$` to denote a cached jQuery object or a collection of jQuery objects, it makes for an easy visual reference. And yes, you are correct... I did not need to cache the select element in this instance.